# Simulating Mixed Nash Equilibria

Tags: algorithms, game-theory, fixed-point-theorems, nash-equilibrium, algorithmic-game-theory

I have a $N$ person game where each person has a set of $M$ discrete strategies. I know from the theory that at least one mixed strategy Nash Equilibrium exists.

Can someone please tell me how do I find one of those equilibrium points by numerical simulation?

I can not find in the book any explanation of how to simulate. I just need the basic direction.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried naively iterating? I.e., pick a strategy for each of the $N$ players, and each iteration recalculate the optimal strategies.

Comment: @Scaramouche Thank you. I read about the method you mention. It is called best response dynamics in literature (at least I hope that is what you mean). But it seems that this method only converges to the NE in very special kind of games and not in any game. Please correct me if wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recent survey article on the algorithms for computing (mixed strategy) Nash equilibria:
http://www.maths.lse.ac.uk/Personal/stengel/ETissue/ETintro.pdf